# Using Selenium IDE to find dynamic ID

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have been able to locate the element by using the following command, target and Value.

```
Command:  Select
Target:   //div[@id='ui-id-51']/div[2]/div/fieldset/div/div/select
Value:    Documentation
```

This xpath works, however, the id number is dynamic and will change each time that I open up this window a new time. So the number (51 in this example) may be 201 the next time that I open this window, but the ui-id- will always be the same. So this Target is not found the next time I open the window. I have tried using the following xpath to fix this, but it does not work.

```
Command:   Select
Target:    //div[starts-with(@id,'ui-id-')]/div[2]/div/fieldset/div/div/select
Value:     Documentation
```

Can someone give me the correct xpath to find this target with a dynamic id?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ui-id-22" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 552px;">

    <div></div>
    <div class="patient-module-contact-edit">
        <!--

         start of template: "#contact_log_logEntry_edit" 

        -->
        <div class="new-encounter">
            <fieldset class="wide-mode liquid" style="border: none; padding-top: 0px;">
                <div class="row span5">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <label></label>
                        <select class="encounterType vf vf-required span4 vf-validated" name="encounterType" style="visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="INBOUND_TELEPHONE"></option>
                            <option value="OUTBOUND_TELEPHONE"></option>
                            <option value="OUTBOUND_TELEPHONE_VM"></option>
                            <option value="OUTBOUND_TELEPHONE_NO"></option>
                            <option value="INBOUND_EMAIL"></option>
                            <option value="OUTBOUND_EMAIL"></option>
                            <option value="INBOUND_FAX"></option>
                            <option value="OUTBOUND_FAX"></option>
                            <option value="INBOUND_TEXT"></option>
                            <option value="OUTBOUND_TEXT"></option>
                            <option selected="" value="ENCOUNTER"></option>
                            <option value="DOCUMENTATION"></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

`starts-with()` based solution looks good and should work according to what you've provided.

You can also try a bit broader check using [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains):

```
//div[contains(@id,'ui-id-')]/div[2]/div/fieldset/div/div/select
```

Comment: I have tried both of these methods. My test does not fail, but it does not change the value of my target to Documentation, and it does not even highlight the element when running the test. It only highlights and changes that target to documentation when I have the specific id number in my xpath. This is the issue, because that will not work when the id changes. Any other ideas that I could try and experiment with?

Comment: @ltp61992 please add the relevant HTML code that has the target element inside (edit the question and insert it there). Thanks.

Comment: @ltp61992 ok, let's try to get the `select` by `name`: `//select[@name="encounterType"]`. Does it work?

Comment: Again, the test case passed but the element is not highlighted and not changed to Documentation.

Comment: @ltp61992 that's weird, is it the public URL you are testing? If yes, can you provide it and also the exported test case?

Comment: it is not a public URL, is there anything else I could be doing wrong or might be able to try? I really need to be able to change this field in order to complete a lot of testing

Comment: it is in an iframe. that might be the issue also

Comment: @ltp61992 yes, but you are saying if the exact id check is used (via `=`) - it works.